# Having trouble with addEventListerner on link tag

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, addeventlistener

I have a task where I have to add JS to my website navbar: when you click on the second element of the navbar, the first element's name should be changed.

I'm trying to change the first nav element's name when the second element of the nav is clicked.
This is what I have so far:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeName(){
  alert("Second label clicked");
  var el1 = document.getElementById("el1");
  el1.innerHTML = "New name";
}

var el2 = document.getElementById("el2");
el2.addEventListener("click", ChangeName)
</script>
```

And the navigator tag looks like this:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                 
      </button>
      <a id = "el1" class="navbar-brand" href="#">LABEL 1</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li id="el2"><a href="#section1">LABEL 2</a></li>
          <li id="el3"><a href="#section2">LABEL 3</a></li>
          <li id="el4"><a href="#section3">LABEL 4</a></li>
   </div>
</nav>
```

However, it doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure how to use addEventListerner on links.

Comment: You're missing a `</ul></div>`

Comment: Any errors reported in your console?

Comment: Is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener and is not `type="module"`? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](/q/14028959/4642212). I have just tested your code; it works if the `<script>` is placed correctly.

Comment: This issue doesn’t happen in [ES modules](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), so, honestly, just use `<script type="module">`. It’s 2022.

Answer (score 1):

your html is off.  You are missing a closing ul tag and 2 closing div tags.  the rest works.  be sure to add your script just before the closing body tag

```js
  function ChangeName() {
    alert("Second label clicked");
    var el1 = document.getElementById("el1");
    el1.innerHTML = "New name";
  }
var el2 = document.getElementById("el2");
el2.addEventListener("click", ChangeName)
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                 
      </button>
      <a id="el1" class="navbar-brand" href="#">LABEL 1</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li id="el2"><a href="#section1">LABEL 2</a></li>
          <li id="el3"><a href="#section2">LABEL 3</a></li>
          <li id="el4"><a href="#section3">LABEL 4</a></li>

        </ul>

      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: The browser closes unclosed tags automatically. That has no effect on the JS at all.